# Is there a single SQL update statement to handle my scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-update

Given a simple 3 column table with an ID column, a Name column, and a City column, where both City and Name may contain NULL:

I may have content for one or both of the City/Name columns (but at least for one column). Is it possible to write a single update statement to handle all three possible scenarios?

Thanks for any help!

Some clarifications:

1. standard SQL - no vendor-specific code
2. I thought it was self-evident but apparently not: The 3 possible scenarios would be: a) update Name column only, b) update City column only, c) update both
3. For the visual people:

Table: MyTable

```
ID    Name       City
1     Bob        Houston
```

Pseudocode:

```
update MyTable
set Name = <new content if content known, otherwise do not update>
   ,City = <new content if content known, otherwise do not update>
where ID = 1
```

Since I am new here and don't know how many trolls are out and about:
To the question below (is this for real)?
Why would I update a field? Because that's what people do with a DBMS!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you [edited your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62627383/edit) with some clear examples of the update you want to make. Please show what is in the table before, and what is in the table after.

Comment: Besides, add your DBMS, since each DBMS might have its own dialectic for update statements.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And what are the three possible scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CASE expression would do this:

```
update MyTable
  set Name = case when $1 is null then name else $1 end,
      city = case when $2 is null then city else $2 end
where ID = 1;
```

`$1` and `$2` are parameters you provide from within your code. The exact syntax depends on the driver/interface you are using (in JDBC this would be `?` rather than `$x`)